# How to send AT commands between to invoke an app in android when the screen is locked?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have a device which supports HFP and BLE. We are sending an AT+ command to trigger and open the application on Android phone. We are unable to do so when the phone is in locked state. 
Can you kindly guide me how to achieve this.

Comment: Question is not related to bluetooth HFP. Looks like the question is about actions you perform on android app when received AT commands.